# Is there any way to create zip in a zip file using java dynamically..?

Tags: java, dynamic, zip, compression, archive

I have a bunch of files, say 4 files.. I want to zip 2 files to a zip say "inner.zip"
And the rest to the parent directory of "outer.zip".

I.e

[image]

```
InputStream streamToReadFile=readFile(filePath);
String zipEntryName = folderName + "/" + fileNameToWrite;
ZipEntry anEntry = new ZipEntry(zipEntryName);

// I couldn't able to create zip in a zip file.

streamToWriteInZip.putNextEntry(anEntry);
while ((bytesIn = streamToReadFile.read(readBuffer)) > 0) {
                    streamToWriteInZip.write(readBuffer, 0, bytesIn);
                }
```

Comment: Why would you want to make zip inside zip? Why not just a folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner ZipOutputStream should call `finish()` instead of `close()` as `finish()` flushes all compressed data, but does not close the outer zip. *Mind to test the erroneousness of `close()` one would need to add yet another file, as the inner zip is last.*

```
    Path sourcePath = Paths.get("C:/D/test.html");
    try (ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream("C:/D/test/test.zip"))) {

        zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("file1.txt"));
        Files.copy(sourcePath, zipOut);
        zipOut.closeEntry();

        zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("file2.txt"));
        Files.copy(sourcePath, zipOut);
        zipOut.closeEntry();

        zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("inner.zip"));
        ZipOutputStream innerZipOut = new ZipOutputStream(zipOut);
        {
            innerZipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("file3.txt"));
            Files.copy(sourcePath, innerZipOut);
            innerZipOut.closeEntry();

            innerZipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("file4.txt"));
            Files.copy(sourcePath, innerZipOut);
            innerZipOut.closeEntry();

            innerZipOut.finish(); // Instead of close().
        }
        zipOut.closeEntry();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // Invoke close().
```